# How to iter through rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have to iterate through rows in my code but it keeps giving me an InvalidIindexError. Here is my code

```
sd = pd.read_excel('DF.xlsx')
for row in sd.iterrows():
    url1 = 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/' + sd[row]
    url1
```

it's probably a stupid mistake but it still give me the InvalidIndexError.
Can anybody help me

i was expecting "https://www.google.com/finance/quote/IRFC:NSE"

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: `iterrows` returns two values, so `row` is a tuple, which is an invalid index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterrows gives you a tuple with two entires, for the index and the row itself. So typically you would do

```
for index, row in sd.iterrows():
```

Also within that loop you don't need to slice the whole dataframe unless you want to access a row other than the one from the current loop. So I think the code for what you're trying to do should be something like

```
for index, row in sd.iterrows():
    url1 = 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/' + row['column_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message "InvalidIndexError" is likely due to an incorrect use of the iterrows() method in the for loop. The iterrows() method returns an iterator that yields pairs of index and row data, so the row variable in the loop should be assigned to the second element of each pair, which is the row data.

```
sd = pd.read_excel('DF.xlsx')
for index, row in sd.iterrows():
    url1 = 'https://www.google.com/finance/quote/' + row['column_name']
    print(url1)
```

just Replace 'column_name' with the name of the column that contains the data you want to use in the URL.